# Joining two rows with the same value and then using Count in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a table called sales with the following columns.

- `transaction_id`
- `transaction_refund_id`
- `price`

| id | transaction_id | transaction_refund_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tr_001 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | tr_002 | tr_001 | 5 |
| 3 | tr_003 | tr_003 | 5 |

I want to query the sales table and join the records that match values (transaction_id = transaction_refund_id) then ->count()

I have tried whereColumn but discovered that it's for comparing rows in the same record.

So the value for the count, in this case, is 1 as I am only able to join tr_001

Also tried:

```
Sales::all()->groupBy(['transaction_id', 'transaction_refund_id'])
```

Comment: You can use a combination of join(), whereColumn(), groupBy(), and count() clauses in your query.

Comment: Try: $count = Sales::join('sales AS s2', 'sales.transaction_id', '=', 's2.transaction_refund_id')
    ->whereColumn('sales.transaction_id', '=', 'sales.transaction_refund_id')
    ->groupBy('sales.transaction_id')
    ->count();

Answer (score 0):

u can just write a raw query for that

```
Sales::join("sales as refunded", "sales.transaction_id", "refunded.transaction_refund_id")
->groupBy("sales.transaction_id")
->selectRaw("sales.transaction_id, count(refunded.transaction_refund_id) as count")
->get()
```